# Pycharm : Robot Framework: SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am using Pycharm latest version as given below whenever I pass chrome as browser in my Robot test case it gives me the exception as "***SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75***"

However, I have proper chromedriver that supports my current browser version of 77.0.3865.90 is placed under /user/local/bin with all correct permissions. Just to cross check, I have checked with firefox and it worked.

can you please let me how to resolve this as I need to run test on chrome.

---------------Pycharm details ---------------

PyCharm 2019.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-192.6817.19, built on September 25, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b304.69 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6

Comment: If selenium is reporting an incompatible version of chromedriver, it's not going to lie about that. Maybe you have multiple versions of chrome, or multiple versions of chromedriver.

Comment: I have only one version of chrome and only one chromedriver in said location. Just to cross check again I did run the same test configuration using RED and eclipse IDE and it worked fine with same chromedriver.

Comment: It got resolved by replacing changing the required chromedriver version in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/. this is nothing but pycache location where it picks up